# Removing all Binary Search Tree in one function

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, tree

I have a C program for AVL Tree. I've coded all of the necessary functions for creating node, creating tree, inserting element into tree and so on. Everything works fine, but I couldn't manage to have a `tree_free` function which works. I want this function to remove all of the tree.  Here are my structs ;

```
typedef struct NODE_s *NODE;
typedef struct NODE_s
{  
    NODE right;
    NODE left;
    unsigned long long data;
    int height;
} NODE_t[1];

typedef struct TREE_s *TREE;
typedef struct TREE_s
{
    NODE root;
} TREE_t[1];
```

Here is how I insert numbers in my tree;

```
void avl_insert(TREE tree, unsigned long long data){


    tree->root = avl_insert_recursive(tree->root, data);

}
```

And here is the avl_insert_recursive function;

```
NODE avl_insert_recursive(NODE node, unsigned long long data){

    int balance = 0;


    if( node == NULL){

        return(node_init(data));
    }

    if( data < node->data ){


        node->left = avl_insert_recursive(node->left, data);



    }else if( data > node->data){


        node->right = avl_insert_recursive(node->right, data);



    }else{

        return node;
    }

    node->height = 1 + max(local_height(node->left), local_height(node->right));

    return node;
}
```

As you can see, a number is inserted into a node first of all. Then the node is inserted into the tree. That's why I have 2 functions for removing the three. The first function is simply removing nodes;

```
void node_free(NODE node){

    if(node != NULL){

    node_free(node->left); 
    node_free(node->right); 
    free(node);

    }
}
```

And I call this function from the main `tree_free` function ;

```
void tree_free(TREE tree){

    node_free(tree->root);

}
```

So that's all codes you need to understand how the tree works. I placed a `printf` statement after `tree_free', and it is never executed. So, the program is crashing when it comes the line with`tree_free` function. Thanks for the help.

Edit: For the ones who wanted to see `node_init` function, here you are;

```
NODE node_init(unsigned long long data)
{

    NODE newNode = (struct NODE_s*)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE_s));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->height = 1; 
    return newNode;
}
```

I have a test function to test my AVL Tree;

```
void test(char *fname, int n)
{

// Create tree and initalized it.
TREE tree;
tree = tree_init();


//NODE node = node_init(NULL);

time_t start, end;
int avl_insertion_time = 0;

FILE *fp;
int i = 0;
unsigned long long number;

unsigned long long *inorder = (unsigned long long *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long)*n);
fp = fopen(fname, "r+");
time(&start);
for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
    fscanf(fp, "%llu\n", &number);
    //node = avl_insert_recursive(node,number);
    avl_insert(tree, number);
}
time(&end);
fclose(fp);
avl_insertion_time = end - start

time(&start);
inorder_traversal(tree->root, inorder);
time(&end);
printf("inorder_traversal function's time spent is %ld second for %d number of elements.(AVL insertion was %ld secs)\n", (end - start), n, avl_insertion_time);
tree_free(tree);
free(inorder);
}
```

And here is my main function;

```
int main()
{


test("10000.txt", 10000);
test("100000.txt", 100000);
test("1000000.txt", 1000000);
test("10000000.txt", 10000000);


return 0;
}
```

Here is the function to traverse my tree;

```
void inorder_traversal(NODE node, unsigned long long *inorder){


if (node == NULL){
    return; 
}


inorder_traversal(node->left, inorder); 



inorder[index] = node->data;
index++;



inorder_traversal(node->right, inorder); 


}
```

Comment: you need to show `node_init` function to make sure you are setting `left` and `right` pointers to NULL.

Comment: @kiranBiradar, I've added node_init function at the last of my question, you can check it.

Comment: @DavideSpataro, How I would I do that ? Do you have any link to show me how to debug a spesific function ?

Comment: @OzanYurtsever `I placed a printf statement after tree_free', and it is never executed` try putting `\n` at the end of the `printf` or do `fflush(stdin)`. Also provide[mcve].

Comment: @kiranBiradar, Actually when I tried again, the printf statement is executed for the first call. But I try all the system for several number sets sequentially. So after first tree is created and first number set are inserted into the tree, the tree must be removed to let new number set will be inserted into new tree. So it is not working as sequentially.

Comment: @kiranBiradar, any idea ? I still couldn't fix the problem

Comment: You need to provide [mcve].

Comment: @kiranBiradar, can you tell me what exactly do you want me to provide from my program ? I simplified the program as much as possible...

Comment: @OzanYurtsever A minimal code such that I can try out myself and still produce the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184581/discussion-between-ozan-yurtsever-and-kiran-biradar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `index` is global variable.

The problem is you are not resetting the global `index`.

```
inorder[index] = node->data;
index++;
```

After the first call to `test` your index will be `10000`.

Hence you access

```
inorder[10000+100000] in the second `test` call.
```

---

Thus reset the index after every call to `test`.

```
int main()
{

index = 0;
test("10000.txt", 10000);
index = 0;
test("100000.txt", 100000);
index = 0;
test("1000000.txt", 1000000);
index = 0;
test("10000000.txt", 10000000);


return 0;
}
```